# how can i whrit ((x+12)^2-y^3)) with this variables

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function that calculates the floor division of the following mathematical expression ((x+12)^2-y^3)) by 9.

```
# change the function parameters if you need 
def test(a, b):
  # write your code below this line 
  
  x = int(a)
  y = int(b)
  
  
  return # write here the returned value of the function  
  # Write your code above this line
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. This is quite clearly homework and we're not here to just write code for you.

Comment: thats my first time use his site and i didnt know how its work and its not a homework i just see it in internet and cant solve it @Henry

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://flexiple.com/python/arithmetic-operators-in-python/). It describes all of the operators you need with examples. In future, please try to do your own research before asking a question, then include what you've tried.

Comment: i have posted an answer, but will suggest that you look at the site @Henry suggested or this site here: [variables](https://sites.google.com/view/python-programming-01/basics/variables).   There are a number of resources.

Answer (score 0):

python is quite good at this. Here is a simple recipe.

- define a function `def`.
- pass in variables `x, y`
- do the usual mathematical operations
- `return` the value

Now you can call the function and print the result.

```py
def func(x, y):
    r = ((x+12)**2) - (y**3)
    r_floor = r // 9

    return r_floor 

r = func(10, 5)
print(r)
```

The result in the example above is:

```
39
```